# Parallelism in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I  have a doubt in oracle, for example if you have a function in Oracle, that Function receive one integer parameter.

**Function test(param IN number)**

- When i send param = 1 -> return 100
- When i send param = 2 -> return 300
- When i send param = 3 -> return 200

What happens if three or more users execute the same time the test function, what is result?

user 1:

```
    select test(1) from dual;
```

user 2:

```
    select test(3) from dual;
```

user 3:

```
    select test(2) from dual;
```

Each user get different result?, although the function is execute the same time

Answer (score 0):

If you have the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test ( param IN NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN CASE param
         WHEN 1 THEN 100
         WHEN 2 THEN 300
         WHEN 3 THEN 200
         END;
END;
/
```

Then running:

```sql
SELECT test(1),
       test(2),
       test(3)
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TEST(1) | TEST(2) | TEST(3)
> ------: | ------: | ------:
>     100 |     300 |     200
> ```

If you want to set up scheduled jobs so that 3 users will run the query at the same times then you will find that the results are the same and they each get different outputs.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cdbec580313cc3d07805dfc57e4cef85)*